# if else in Jade for one line variation with children elements

Tags: express, pug

I would like to make my code more DRY, and am struggling with how to get a single line in an if/else statement, while keeping the children divs under the result of the if/else statement.

I have tried curly braces, however, I was unable to get it to work.
Thanks!

```
    if (viewOptions.visible == 'true')
        .myDiv1        
    else
        .myDiv1(style="display:none")
           //either way children get added to myDiv1
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to use a mixin and `&attributes(attributes)` from the pug docs: https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html

```
if (viewOptions.dataVisibility == 'true')
      +propertySection('My input', "enter a number", source._data.length, 'myInputName')            
    else 
      +propertySection('My input', "enter a number", source._data.length, 'myInputName')(style="display:none")

mixin propertySection(header, label, initVal, inputName)
  .myDiv1&attributes(attributes)
    .myHeader= header
    .myLabel= label
    input(value='#{initVal}' name="#{inputName}")
```